# How can I install both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: system-installation

I have an 80 GB hard drive and 8 GB of RAM. Do I need to make a partition to install Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 alongside each other?

I have tried but I could not do it. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a LiveCD or USB drive with the bootable Ubuntu image on it. Boot into the CD or USB drive and select "Try Ubuntu" then on the Ubuntu desktop open the "Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" icon. Follow the on screen instructions and when you get to the "Installation Type" screen choose to install Ubuntu alongside your Windows 7. If it does not work or you need any more assistance, please leave a comment.